# How do I pass data from an EditText in one Activity to a TextView in another activity without switching to the second activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to send a string variable that is entered into an EditText on ActivityOne to pass the data and be displayed as a TextView on ActivityThree. However, I am having problems as the only solutions to do this that I can find cause the activity to switch to ActivityThree while doing this. I want to avoid this or maybe even send the data to ActivityThree and switch to ActivityTwo all on the click of a button. Any help or redirection to a current solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use sharedpreference to save your current input in your current activity and display it to the another activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from ActivityOne to ActivityThree by avoiding ActivityTwo then save that data in a static variable then use that variable in ActivityThree to set TextView data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using `SharedPreferences`.

1. Setting `EditText` values in `Preference` from `ActivityOne`:

   ```
    // EditText
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Your_Preference_Name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("KEY_VALUE", editText.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
   ```
2. In `ActivityThree`, retrieve value from `Preference`:

   ```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Your_Preference_Name", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String editTextValue = prefs.getString("KEY_VALUE", null);

    // TextView
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(editTextValue);
   ```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

Please use a global variable in Application class and set it's value in ActivityOne and read the same value from ActivityThree.Global variables are available to entire project Activities.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using input extra. Do this in Activity one

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityThree.class);
i.putExtra("label", "label_text");
startActivity(i);
```

Then receive the string in Activity three as such:

```
EditText input = //intialize it in OnCreate
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getExtras().getString("label");
input.setText(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do this.. But it heavily depends on what you plan to do with data and your situation.. 
If you want to **display** the data in activity three than you can make data `persist` and later show it when activity three is **created or resumed**, now:

1- If you want to **display** the data in activity three and you want the value to persist only in **current session** you can use a `Global Variable` or even **Static** one, if you define the desired value as a static variable inside your activity three than you can easily access it and use it without any need for the activity to be even created:

```
public ActivityThree extends Activity {
    public static String myValue;
```

2- If you want to **display** the data in activity three and you want data to **persist** even if the **app is closed** you can use `SharedPreferences` as described here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

3- If you want to run a **background task** in activity three on value getting determined you can use `LocalBroadcastManager`:
https://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-service-to-activity-communications/